# Is there a way to access my Reading List without opening Safari?

Tags: safari, reading-list

I am reading on iPad and saving to reading list. I don't like Safari on OS X and don't want to open it every time. Is there a way to access the links in my Reading List without opening Safari?

Comment: Are you talking about the "off line" reading list. Where you can save the links (and the web page content) so you can read it later even if you are not on line.

Comment: I am reading on iPad and saving to reading list. is there a way to browse the list other than accessing it from desktop Safari?